Conditional Formatting for a Dynamic Named Range with Blanks
I have a dynamic named range in Microsoft Excel, using the following formula...
=$P$2:INDEX($2:$1048576,COUNTA($P:$P),COUNTA($2:$2))

However, it does not return the entire width of the range, and I believe it's because there are some blank cells in the range.
For context, the width of the range will always be 12 rows. So, in my worksheet, the width of the dynamic named range will never go beyond column AA. Of course, since it is dynamic, the height of the data will always change.
Also, the named range is on a FILTER formula. Not sure if that might be the reason why it's not outputting correctly, but thought I'd mention that in case it's causing the problem. I was under the assumption that dynamic named ranges work even with FILTER functions.
I'm referencing the named range in this formula. The INDEX(CHAR(SEQUENCE section is to create a blank row in between the sets of data.
IFERROR(
VSTACK(
ActiveF_TOTALS,
ActiveFILTERED,
INDEX(CHAR(160),,SEQUENCE(1,12,1,0)),
NonActiveF_TOTALS,
NonActiveFILTERED,
INDEX(CHAR(160),,SEQUENCE(1,12,1,0)),
PendingF_TOTALS,
PendingFILTERED,
INDEX(CHAR(160),,SEQUENCE(1,12,1,0)),
DormantF_TOTALS,
DormantFILTERED
),
""
)

Any idea on how I can make dynamic named ranges work and output correctly if they have random blank cells within the range?
Thanks for your help.
